# Are security questions on-topic here?

Tags: discussion, site-scope

First of all, welcome to this new SE site!

I was wondering if we should allow security questions, as securing the communication between IoT devices (e.g. [How do I secure communication between app and IoT device?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/19/im-building-a-system-that-includes-a-mobile-app-and-a-bluetooth-enabled-hardwar)) on this site or if they are better suited for [information security SE](https://security.stackexchange.com/)

Answer (score 9):

Expanding from my comment, my view is that any question which is specifically about the security **of IoT devices** is a perfectly valid question here. For example, take this title of a question:

> [What are the best security practices to follow when building an IoT device?](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/14/what-are-the-best-security-practices-to-follow-when-building-an-iot-device)

As you can see, this question is mainly about IoT, not just security in general and the title doesn't give much scope for discussing other devices (which is good, in my opinion!).

On the other hand, questions which are **about** security but are tangentially related to IoT should be migrated or closed (depending on the quality of the question and how on-topic it would be at Security).

Also, I don't think [security](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security) is right for travel-related questions, because that **isn't** really security - perhaps [travel](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/travel) would be a better tag?

Comment: The question is too broad, but sub-sets of that question (relating specifically to low-cost, unmaintained, high volume) seem particularly on-topic.

Comment: Agree with Sean. "Best Practices" questions are inherently not a fit for the Stack Exchange concept because they are broad and opinionated.  But *specifics* of securing *specific* IoT systems would be a fit here.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say it clearly depends. I actually cast a bunch of close votes because I think we got a handful of basic network security questions where the IoT aspect is negligible. That being said, clearly security is one of the most important topics in any IoT implementation.

Thus, I think we need good judgement when those questions come in. If there's nothing specific to IoT close it fast. Don't answer it.

I also totally agree with Aurora on the [security](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/security). That should only pertain to device security of the IoT device.

We might even consider creating a sub-tag [device-security](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/device-security) about *hackability* of the IoT device and one general one for the security of the complete system. This might be prudent since security on embedded connected devices has a different problems to face than network and system security in general.

Comment: Mostly agree, however IoT security would extend to IoT protocols and not just IoT devices.  So for example, an exploit *via* MQTT against an MQTT broker off in the cloud somewhere would be on-topic.  But an exploit against the MQTT broker's generic server operating system would be off topic, because the kinship is to server security in general, not to IoT.