# This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network

Tags: discussion, migration

[This question](https://iot.stackexchange.com/questions/764/could-a-blockchain-really-prevent-malware-in-the-internet-of-things) belongs on the [Security Stack Exchange.](https://security.stackexchange.com/)

When I voted to close it as belonging to another site, the only option I had was here on meta.

I have seen quite a few questions which clearly belong on Security; not to mention SuperUser, Software recommendations and even S.O.

Such posts will only persist if we allow them and do not discourage false-posting.

Is it just that I don't have enough points to see them, or do other sites simple not exists as an option? And, if not, why not?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While Ghanima already addressed why we don't have migration paths yet, there are two steps to migrating a question of which you skipped at least the first one.

1. *Decide—**as a community**—that the question is off-topic.*
   However, just because something is—or might be—on-topic somewhere else that doesn't mean it has to off-topic here. First we decide for ourselves if we want to allow a question. That hasn't happened yet with that question.
2. *Determine a proper target site.* Looking at the [on-topic page](https://security.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) from the Security Stack Exchange, I'm not sure that the question would be welcome there in the current state. Remember, migrating questions is not using a trash can, it's about getting questions that are no fit at the source site to where they are a fit. Both have to be true.

   Both are also **a vehicle to get the user a high quality answer.** That's why it's strongly discouraged to migrate questions with an answer or even several answers. Migrating a question that has about twenty upvotes in answers would completely defeat that purpose.

Anyhow, the [draft](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/a/210/78) that has been discussed in chat clearly includes IoT security questions for the site scope. Security is our second-most-used tag. Furthermore, *figuring out that a method is not really applicable **to IoT** is a very valid answer to a question about **IoT-applicability** of a method.*

Answer (score 3):

> When I voted to close it as belonging to another site, the only option I had was here on Meta.

That's to be expected as of now as the migration paths are not set up. We (as a community) will have to decide which sites are the most relevant for possible migrations here and have CM set those up for us.

See also: [What is migration and how does it work?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/10249/284388)

Comment: "We (as a community) will have to decide which sites are the most relevant for possible migrations" - then let the voting begin!   How shall we proceed?

Comment: I have started a new topic http://meta.iot.stackexchange.com/q/213/54 either use the CW answer - or perhaps better, post answers to make a case for a certain site and have it voted for.

Comment: Note that there will not be any migration paths before the site graduates. Until then, only moderators can migrate.

Comment: @Gilles I was not aware (or forgot about that). In that case we need not focus on this issue.

Answer (score 3):

I wrote this question, so I do hope this doesn't sound  as if I'm trying to simply shout you down or prove you wrong; this is a fundamental question of the beta and it's worth discussing.

The question [*Are security questions on-topic here?*](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3/are-security-questions-on-topic-here) is worth a read if you haven't already read it - I realise that my answer is the top there, and it might sound like I'm trying to prove a point with my own posts, so I do apologise!

The [Meta Stack Exchange policy](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10249/what-is-migration-and-how-does-it-work) on migration has some information which may be helpful in this discussion:

> **Don't migrate for the sake of migration.** We only migrate questions because they are off-topic on the original site. It is perfectly possible for a question to be on-topic on multiple sites, but that is not a reason to migrate it elsewhere. As a general rule, if someone asks a question here, and it's on-topic here, it should stay here.

A Stack Exchange question *can* be on-topic in multiple places, and I chose to ask on IoT because I was interested in specific applications to the security of the Internet of Things, rather than generic answers about how blockchains could potentially secure devices. For my question specifically,  I also considered that since blockchains are **fundamentally made of networked devices**, it would be more applicable here - blockchain-based security probably wouldn't work for a single device, but would be helpful in a larger network.

I think, more generally, IoT is quite a broad field covering many disciplines, from electronics, to consumer hardware/software, to security and privacy, and I'm personally happy with that - an overly specific scope would quickly get boring, so I believe we should embrace any questions that are relevant and interesting to our field - whether a question *could* be asked somewhere else is immaterial to the argument, and we should judge whether a question is on-topic or not *as if migration never existed*.

Comment: You wrote the question - and I voted it off topic & started this discussion. I am upvoting you for getting some good discussion going here. You have very high rep here and obviously are not asking trivial questions. I voted it OT pertly because I do think that it is. I still see nothing IoT specific - sure, it can be used *with* IoT, but it is not *for* IoT. But the main reason that I wanted to migrate it is that I truly believe that the experts on the security site know more about security than we do here. Continued ...

Comment: You say "since blockchains are fundamentally made of networked devices, it would be more applicable here" and are probably correct ***in theory*** (so I can even agree that it can be within scope, BUT which site is going to get you the best quality answers? Surely it's security? Let's see what others say, not so much about that one question, but just in general.

Comment: @Mawg: you do have a point with where the experts may be, and migration would make a lot of sense if there weren't any answers. However, at the minute, there are 5 (good quality) answers, so I suspect the whole benefit of migration would be negated, because the answers are already here. I don't see any benefit in closing/migrating if the answers here are good already, but the answer might be entirely different if the question sat around for a week with no response. I suppose it's just a difference in migration philosophy - feedback from others would be helpful to gauge the general opinion.

Comment: Quite right about the existing answers. I hope that you get one that helps you.

Answer (score 3):

To me, this question is clearly on topic. Maybe the answers are a bit generic, but blockchain has been proposed as relevant to IoT, and that seems relevant (regardless of the answer and how much the primary discussion which supported the question was clickbait). Security is the big IoT issue...