# What should our off-topic migration paths be?

Tags: discussion, site-scope, migration

Triggered by this question [This question belongs on another site in the Stack Exchange network](https://iot.meta.stackexchange.com/q/211/54) and the ongoing discussion of on-/off-topicness we need to agree on our main migration paths. As they appear when vote to close a question as off-topic is done, they are an important tool for community moderation, i.e.  for anyone using VTC privileges.

Answers to this question should finally result in a list of possible migration paths, i.e. the most appropriate sites, the ones which we will be migrating to most often.

As always: remember not to migrate crap and being off-topic here does not mean being on-topic somewhere else.

Candidates:

- [Electrical Engineering](https://electronics.stackexchange.com)
- [Security](https://security.stackexchange.com)
- [SuperUser](https://superuser.com)
- [U&L](https://unix.stackexchange.com/)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question because it's far too early to raise the issue. Until the site graduates, which is months or years away, there will not be any migration path (this rule has been applied almost systematically by Stack Exchange). Beyond this rule, to decide about migration paths, we need to have experience of what has needed migrating in the past.

Comment: @gilles as I said on your other comment, I forget about that. If there is no need for migration paths we need not worry for now.

Answer (score 5):

I'd say we wait until we actually have a question that merits—by community decision—a migration. The slots are limited and users are encouraged to only migrate to sites of which they know the question would be welcome there. We don't have enough migration-privileged users that have that knowledge of these target sites.

Considering migration it's important to remember, [if you're not sure, don't migrate it.](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/10250/338924) So until we have that voting base of people who can in good conscience migrate to those sites we shouldn't open any preset migration paths. For the amount of expected migrations there will always be the pro-tem moderators who can migrate *right away (tm)*, meaning after checking in with the receiving site.

Answer (score 1):

I have seen at least one each which belongs on   Stack Overflow, Software Recommendations and Hardware Recommendations.

But, I imagine that we don't want to offer **every** SE site as a migration option.

Sooner or later, someone will have a question about his IoT enabled https://bicycles.stackexchange.com/  Hmmm, do self driving cars belong here or on https://mechanics.stackexchange.com/ ?

I think we will soon decide on the most likely handful and don't need to offer every low runner possibility.